# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'. please can anyone help me?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class RequestAssistant
{
  static Future<dynamic> getRequest(String url) async

  {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);  //this is my error (url)

    if(response.statusCode == 200)
      {
        String jSonData = response.body;
        var decodeData = jsonDecode(jSonData);
        return decodeData;

      }
    else
      {
        return "Failed, No Response.";
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try final _url =  Uri.tryParse(url);. And then http.Response response = await http.get(_url);

Comment: still not working

Comment: "still not working" means absolutely nothing to us.  Please describe what you changed, what you expected, and what it did.

Answer (score 1):

It will work for you:

```
http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: hi abbass how r u? bro iam facing a problem while running the app:  Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found. how can i fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Just parse String to Uri.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class RequestAssistant
{
  static Future<dynamic> getRequest(String url) async

  {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url));  //this is my error (url)

    if(response.statusCode == 200)
      {
        String jSonData = response.body;
        var decodeData = jsonDecode(jSonData);
        return decodeData;

      }
    else
      {
        return "Failed, No Response.";
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with recent upgrades, http doesn't accept type String. Below change should work for you-

```
final Uri newUrl = Uri.parse(url); //add this line
http.Response response = await http.get(newUrl);
```

Comment: still not working newUrl = Uri.parse(url)
    http.Response response = await http.get(newUrl);

Comment: remember to add " ; " after this line:  newUrl = Uri.parse(url)

Comment: modified answer with ";". what error are you getting after adding Uri.parse() line?

Comment: newUrl = Uri.parse(url); // newUrl error
    http.Response response = await http.get(newUrl); // also this (newUrl) 
both are red